Why a connection in parallel between a capacitor and an inductor is "violating" KCL?
I'm learning about impedance; I have a simple AC circuit (two resistors, one capacitor and one inductor):

The AC voltage is 10 V peak (7.07 RMS) at 240 Hz.
I calculated the equivalent/total impedance of the circuit and is
Zt = 39.8693 ∠ -75.47 deg
But then, simulating I got this:

This is violating the KCL!
If I change the frequency to something like 30 Hz or to something like 1 kHz this does not occur.
Am I missing something? Is this a problem with my simulator?
I would really appreciate your answers, have a good day!

EDIT: Thaks to your answers, so, thanks to the calculations i got that the Irms current is:
Irms = 0.177[A]
But why the first ammeter is marking 0.2[A]?
Thanks again!

EDIT #2: I solve it in my notebook but instead of taking an ugly picture i decided to ask chat GPT in order to paste here the calculations

So, according to the answer of @Jan Eerland, ChatGPT and my calculations this is correct
So, in conclusion, maybe my version of proteus is kind of buggy in this specific kind of situations?, that could be the conclusion?
And if thats the case, maybe i must not rely so much on proteus next time

Did you consider the phases of these currents when checking KCL?

Does the simulator documentation describe what the AC ammeters (AC Amps) report when the load is not resistive (i.e. when the voltage and current are not in phase)?

@a360pilot Not really, i thought that AC KCL it was the same as DC KCL (not considering phase angle and just the modulus of the current), so, i must consider phase angle in everything? (as KCL or KVL)?

@ChesterGillon In the simulator it only says this: "The AC voltmeters and ammeters display the true RMS values integrated over a user definable time constant"
I searched in the "user manual" and i found the same thing

@proprogrammer yes. Think of the ammeters as showing the magnitudes of the individual vectors. How would you derive the magnitude of the sum vector? Would you need to consider the angle between the vectors? Phasors are vectors, by the way!

Right!, thanks man!, if i use KCL with the fasors/vector form it makes sense!, but something still dont make sense to me, if the Irms (vector form) is 0.0444+0.1716j and Irms (modulus/amplitud) is then 0.177[A], why the first ammeter is outputing 0.2[A]?
That still dont make sense to me (and also i dont know why the current in the capacitor and the current in the inductor is greater than the 0.177[A])

@proprogrammer What is the integration period set to? The integration period must encompass an even number of cycles. If this is a transient analysis, then you need start recording information after about 50ms to get rid of the startup ringing.

@qrk Is set to 100ms :/ BTW, i simulated this using Multisim and it result on Irms=183[mA] (still not showing 0.177[A] but at least its closer)

Also, the result of the analysis showed that the Irms current leads voltage by 75.47 degrees, but this is not what proteus oscilloscope is showing, i will let a picture and a calculus as an edit

See my answer regarding the 0.20 A. Did you use a slider to set the frequency? Did you use a division to set the frequency? Did you somewhere use 3.14 as the value of pi? I don't know where the error crept in, but a slightly different frequency gives the values in the screen shot.

im gonna check your answer! @MathKeepsMeBusy , and no, i actually just input the value in the 'frequency' box, i even use another ac voltage source element but i got the same result
And no, i never use pi in the simulation and i use the value of pi directly from the calculator (the "macro" pi)

@My thought is that there is a 1.9 Ohm resistance in your inductor model. (Maybe 2.0 Ohm, but 1.9 is what my calculations give). This would make the current ratio between the L and C correct, and would also give 0.202 A as the current through the first ammeter. See my edited answer.

What you are seeing in the loop containing the inductor and capacitor is resonance. That is why the current in that loop is higher than the current into or out of that loop. But you will notice that the sum of all the currents into the node connecting the LC loop with the outer circuits is 0. I.e. 0.2 + 0.83 - 1.03 = 0. So Kirchhoff's Current Law (KCL) holds at that node (and all other nodes!).
Although the inductor and capacitor are resonating, you are not driving them at their resonant frequency. If you were driving them at the resonant frequency, and they were ideal components, the parallel impedance of the inductor and capacitor would be infinite, and you would have no current flowing out of the AC source. Because you are not driving the parallel L and C at their resonant frequency, their combined impedance is either capacitative or inductive, depending upon whether the driving frequency is above or below the resonant frequency.
Let's call the net reactance of the L and C in parallel simply X, and the total resistance in your two resistors R, then the magnitude of the net impedance will be
$$Z = \sqrt{R^2 + X^2}$$
Once you find \$Z\$, the magnitude of the current through the voltage source will obey:
$$V = IZ$$.
Note that in these formulas I am using magnitudes not phasors. So in this case, the current can be found simply by dividing \$V\$ by \$Z\$.
$$I = \frac{V}{Z}$$.

But why the first ammeter is marking 0.2[A]?

In order for the rms current through the inductor to be 0.83 A, while the rms current through the capacitor to be 1.03 A, the ratio between the inductor's impedance and the capacitor's impedance must be 1.03:0.83.
Since you have verified that the frequency in your simulation is 240 Hz, that leads me to believe that the model for your inductor has a significant resistance included. (This might be given the symbol DCR in your simulator).
(It is also possible that the capacitor has a large ESR (effective series resistance, but typically, that is much, much, smaller than the resistance of an inductor).
Assuming the capacitor has an impedance of
$$Z_C = \frac{1}{j2\pi f}\;\Omega = -6.631 j\;\Omega$$
the inductor must have a total impedance of
$$|Z_L| = \frac{1.03}{0.83}6.631 = 8.229 \;\Omega$$
The inductance itself has a reactance of
$$X_L = 2\pi\times240\;\text{Hz} \times 5.31\;\text{mH} = 8.007\;\Omega$$
So the series resistance of the inductor must be
$$R_L =  \sqrt{8.229^2-8.007^2}\;\Omega = 1.9\;\Omega$$
So the phasor impedance of the inductor is
$$Z_L = (1.9 + j8.007)\;\Omega$$
The inductor and capacitor in parallel have an impedance of
$$Z_{LC} = (0-j6.524)||(1.9+j8.007) = (15.18 - 17.624j)\;\Omega$$
This, in series with the 10 \$\Omega\$ of explicit resistors gives a total impedance of
$$Z_{total} = (25.18 - 17.624j)\Omega = 34.99 \angle -42^{\circ}\;\Omega$$
The current in the first ammeter should then read
$$I = \frac{7.07}{34.99} = 0.202 \;\text{mA}\approx 0.20 \;\text{mA}$$
which is what is shown!

Thanks man! awesome explanation!, well, i just can say that maybe my simulator exact version (old version actually) is buggy or consider something that i cant see and its changing the frequency for some reason , but i stay this time with the calculation, thanks again!

I have read your anser, and it makes sense to me, thats why the calculated current on the capacitor is actually what we can see in the simulation and that would explain why the current on the inductor is less than the calculated

Also, i would like to say that, with your answer, i tested some things, i went to search some commercial inductors, i started with a 8.9uH, i did the calculation, i did the simulation, and everything was perfect, then i change the value to 100uH, the same, then 330uH, the same, then with 2200uH (2.2mH), the same (very very few difference, but i started to see it)

With 2.2mH i expected a rms current of 589[mA] and the simulation showed up 580[mA]; then, i use 3300uH (3.3mH), expected Irms = 317[mA], the simulation showed up 290[mA]

So i guess, at least proteus 8.13, treats inductors (various generic types) as non ideal inductors, so, next time i (or someone who uses the same simulator version), must be careful with the ideal calculations when using generic inductors above 2.2mH

Again, thanks man! very helpful!

Well, notice that your impedance is given by:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\text{Z}_\text{i}&=\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2+\left(\text{j}\omega\text{L}\space\text{||}\space\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{j}\omega\text{C}}\right)\\
\\
&=\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2+\frac{\displaystyle\text{j}\omega\text{L}\cdot\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{j}\omega\text{C}}}{\displaystyle\text{j}\omega\text{L}+\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{j}\omega\text{C}}}\\
\\
&=\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2+\frac{\displaystyle\text{j}\omega\text{L}\cdot\frac{\displaystyle\text{j}\omega\text{C}}{\displaystyle\text{j}\omega\text{C}}}{\displaystyle\text{j}\omega\text{L}\text{j}\omega\text{C}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{j}\omega\text{C}}{\displaystyle\text{j}\omega\text{C}}}\\
\\
&=\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2+\frac{\displaystyle\text{j}\omega\text{L}}{\displaystyle1-\text{CL}\omega^2}
\end{split}\tag1
\end{equation}
Where \$\displaystyle\alpha\space\text{||}\space\beta:=\frac{\displaystyle\alpha\beta}{\displaystyle\alpha+\beta}\$.
Which will give you, for your case:
$$\left|\text{Z}_\text{i}\right|=\frac{\displaystyle5 \sqrt{4779 \pi ^2 \left(76464 \pi ^2-918125\right)+24414062500}}{\displaystyle9558 \pi ^2-78125}\approx39.9\space\Omega\tag2$$
So, the RMS input current is given by:
$$\overline{\text{I}}_\text{i}=\frac{\displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle\hat{\text{V}}_\text{i}}{\displaystyle\sqrt{2}}}{\displaystyle\left|\text{Z}_\text{i}\right|}=\frac{\displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle10}{\displaystyle\sqrt{2}}}{\displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle5 \sqrt{4779 \pi ^2 \left(76464 \pi ^2-918125\right)+24414062500}}{\displaystyle9558 \pi ^2-78125}}\approx0.177\space\text{A}\tag3$$
So, the RMS current through the coil and capacitor is given by:
$$\overline{\text{I}}_\text{C}=\left|\frac{\displaystyle\text{j}\omega\text{L}}{\displaystyle\text{j}\omega\text{L}+\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{j}\omega\text{C}}}\right|\cdot\overline{\text{I}}_\text{i}\approx1.032\text{A}\tag4$$
$$\overline{\text{I}}_\text{L}=\left|\frac{\displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{j}\omega\text{C}}}{\displaystyle\text{j}\omega\text{L}+\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{j}\omega\text{C}}}\right|\cdot\overline{\text{I}}_\text{i}\approx0.855\text{A}\tag5$$

Now, do the same calculations but with the phase, remeber \$\displaystyle\left|\text{z}\right|=\sqrt{\Re^2\left(\text{z}\right)+\Im^2\left(\text{z}\right)}\$. And you'll see what happends.


Edit, hint:
$$\vec{\text{I}}_\text{C}=\frac{\displaystyle\text{j}\omega\text{L}}{\displaystyle\text{j}\omega\text{L}+\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{j}\omega\text{C}}}\cdot\frac{\displaystyle\vec{\text{V}}_\text{i}}{\displaystyle\vec{\text{Z}}_\text{i}}\tag6$$
So, we get:
$$\left|\vec{\text{I}}_\text{C}\right|=\frac{\displaystyle\left|\text{j}\omega\text{L}\right|}{\displaystyle\left|\text{j}\omega\text{L}+\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{j}\omega\text{C}}\right|}\cdot\frac{\displaystyle\left|\vec{\text{V}}_\text{i}\right|}{\displaystyle\left|\vec{\text{Z}}_\text{i}\right|}=\frac{\displaystyle\omega\text{L}}{\displaystyle\left|\omega\text{L}-\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\omega\text{C}}\right|}\cdot\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\left|\vec{\text{Z}}_\text{i}\right|}\cdot\frac{\hat{\text{V}}_\text{i}}{\sqrt{2}}\tag7$$
$$\arg\left(\vec{\text{I}}_\text{C}\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}-\arg\left(\text{j}\left(\omega\text{L}-\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\omega\text{C}}\right)\right)+\arg\left(\vec{\text{V}}_\text{i}\right)-\arg\left(\vec{\text{Z}}_\text{i}\right)\tag8$$
Where:
$$
\arg\left(\text{j}\left(\omega\text{L}-\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\omega\text{C}}\right)\right)=\begin{cases}
0&\space\text{when}\space\omega\text{L}-\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\omega\text{C}}=0\\
\\
\frac{\displaystyle\pi}{\displaystyle2}&\space\text{when}\space\omega\text{L}-\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\omega\text{C}}>0\\
\\
\frac{\displaystyle3\pi}{\displaystyle2}&\space\text{when}\space\omega\text{L}-\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\omega\text{C}}<0
\end{cases}\tag9
$$
$$
\arg\left(\vec{\text{Z}}_\text{i}\right)=\begin{cases}
\frac{\displaystyle\pi}{\displaystyle2}&\space\text{when}\space1-\text{CL}\omega^2=0\\
\\
\arctan\left(\frac{\displaystyle\omega\text{L}}{\displaystyle\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2\right)\left(1-\text{CL}\omega^2\right)}\right)&\space\text{when}\space1-\text{CL}\omega^2>0\\
\\
\frac{\displaystyle3\pi}{\displaystyle2}+\arctan\left(\frac{\displaystyle\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2\right)\left(\text{CL}\omega^2-1\right)}{\displaystyle\omega\text{L}}\right)&\space\text{when}\space1-\text{CL}\omega^2<0
\end{cases}\tag{10}
$$

Thanks for your answer! really helpful, i got that the phase angle of the input current is 75.474 Deg
But i still have one question

If the RMS input current is 0.177[A], why the first ammeter (the one between th AC source and the resistor R1) is outputing 0.2[A]? Is this an error of the simulator? because i expected to see 0.177[A] as output of that ammeter

I wish you had added some intuition into your rather long, tedious answer. I guess what you wrote could also be achieved by running a simulator. Not much of a humanly-readable answer, is it?
